# Typewriter effect P5.JS

Tags: p5.js

js and trying to animate a text for it to look as if it was being typed, but I am stuck with this...

````
var palabra= "Hola!"; =
var pos = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(canvasWH, canvasWH);
  frameRate(10); 
}

function draw() {  
  textFont('Georgia');
  textSize(20);
  
  text(palabra.substring(pos, pos + 1), pos+++, canvasWH/2, canvasWH, 100);

  pos = +++

  // Check if we are at the end to restart animation
  if () {
  //restart animation
  }
}```
````

Comment: What are you stuck with, exactly? Do you get an error? If so, what is it? If not, why isn't the behavior as you expect? Note that `pos+++` should probably be `pos++` and `pos = +++` isn't a thing and should also be `pos++`. It's a good idea to look up your syntax as you go--guessing usually isn't too effective.

Answer (score 0):

`pos++` is the way to increment.

`restartDelay` controls how many frames to wait before clearing after drawing is complete

```js
var palabra= "Hola!";
var pos = 0;
var restartDelay = 5;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
  frameRate(10); 
}

function draw() {  
  background(255);
  textFont('Georgia');
  textSize(20);
  
  text(palabra.substring(0, pos + 1), 50, 50);

  pos++;

  // Check if we are at the end to restart animation
  if (pos > palabra.length + restartDelay) {
  //restart animation
    pos = 0;
    
  }
}
```